# running python script on command line

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python code on terminal that does angle conversions. After starting python by doing "python3" what should I do to run the code?

This is the code:

```
def rad_to_deg(radians):
    pi = math.pi
    degrees = 180 * radians / pi
    return (degrees)
def deg_to_rad(degrees):
    pi = math.pi
    radians = pi * degrees / 180
    return (radians)
```

Comment: `python3` runs an interactive session (i.e., for entering code manually); `python3 [filename]` runs a Python script from a file (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Right Frxstrem. You have to first `cd` to the directory where your script is located then `python3 scriptname.py`. Alternatively, you can put in the full path name rather than changing directories to the scripts location. ie: `python3 C:\Folder1\Folder2\scriptname.py`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling the above code, you can import the functions from your file (e.g. `myfile.py`):

```
import myfile
myfile.rad_to_deg(2) #114.59155902616465
myfile.deg_to_rad(180) #3.141592653589793
```

You could also just import the functions from the `math` library:

```
import math
rad_to_deg = math.degrees
deg_to_rad = math.radians
rad_to_deg(2) #114.59155902616465
deg_to_rad(180) #3.141592653589793
```

Just type it in to your shell. Open the [python](/questions/tagged/python) interpreter, and paste the following in:

```
import math
def rad_to_deg(radians): 
    pi = math.pi 
    degrees = 180 * radians / pi 
    return degrees 

def deg_to_rad(degrees): 
    pi = math.pi 
    radians = pi * degrees / 180 
    return radians
```

Notice the `math` import at the top, because that is included in your functions.

To call these functions:

```
>>> import math
>>> def rad_to_deg(radians): 
...     pi = math.pi 
...     degrees = 180 * radians / pi 
...     return degrees 
... 
>>> def deg_to_rad(degrees): 
...     pi = math.pi 
...     radians = pi * degrees / 180 
...     return radians
... 
>>> rad_to_deg(2)
114.59155902616465
>>> deg_to_rad(180)
3.141592653589793
>>>
```

Comment: Rather than type it all in, why not `import` it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you could, but that isn't what the OP is asking, isn't it?

Comment: It's hard to tell, frankly - *"what should I do to run the code?"* doesn't give much precise information and I'd guess that **they don't know**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ok then, I'll add how to import it from the `math` library.

Comment: No, I mean why not import the functions that *they've already written*? Importing `math` is a prerequisite, otherwise their functions can't work anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure they're in a `.py` file already though